# UILabel Text Not Changing From Text Set in Storyboard in Image Classification App

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel

I need to update the label text depending on what image is classified after being passed through a machine learning model. The machine learning will return whether it's a lemon, lime etc. and I then want to print that to screen. However, when I load the app, the label text doesn't change, it just shows 'Loading...' which is what I set on my storyboard.

I've included the function below as well as its declaration as these are the only instances of the variable.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

   @IBAction func scanImage(buffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: ImageClassifier().model) else { return }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, _ in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }

        //Gets most confident result
        guard let mostConfident = results.first else{ return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if mostConfident.confidence >= 0.9 {

                 let confidenceText = "\n \(Int(mostConfident.confidence * 100.0))% confidence"

                switch mostConfident.identifier {
                case "Lemon":
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Lemon. \(confidenceText)"
                case "Lime":
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Lime. \(confidenceText)"
                case "Red Onion":
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Red Onion. \(confidenceText)"
                case "Brocolli":
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Brocolli. \(confidenceText)"
                case "Spring Onion":
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Spring Onion. \(confidenceText)"
                default:
                    return
                }
            } else {
                self.resultLabel.text = "I don't know what this is, try again!"
            }
        }
    }

    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: buffer, options: [:])

    do {
        try requestHandler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Would anybody be able to suggest what I'm doing wrong and why it isn't changing?

Comment: Add breakpoint and check if your method is not stopped somewhere before the text setting. Also, check if resultLabel is not nil and the last thing is just to recreate the IBOutlet remove the label from the storyboard and from the code and recreate it.

Comment: How do I test for nil on the variable?

Comment: if resultLabel == nil { print("My IBOutlet is not linked") } :) I think it will help you